# How to control camera resolution for webrtc in chrome?

Tags: webrtc

We are using webrtc in chrome to do video conferencing.

That works but it uses our webcam with a bad resolution and in 4:3 aspect ratio. The cam however can deliver HD video in 16:9 format.

How can I control this?
By changing Windows settings, chrome configuration or html code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can include a request for a specific resolution in the constraints object passed to getUserMedia. For example:

```
window.navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({
  audio: true,
  video: {optional:[ {minHeight:720}, {minWidth:960} ]}
}, onSuccess, onError);
```

Comment: Finally got to test it. Works great. Thanks.